# Visual Studio のコードレンズに間接的なテストからの参照を認識させる方法

Tags: c#, visual-studio, テスト

Visual Studio のコードレンズではそのメソッド(等)への参照の数、および参照しているテストの数と結果が表示されます。しかし、テストコードで一度別の関数を呼び、さらにその関数の中で目的のコードを使用した場合、そのテストの結果は表示されません。
これを解決する方法はあるのでしょうか。

```
public class App {
    // 全てのテストが成功したことが表示される
    public static int Add(int lhs, int rhs) {
        return lhs + rhs;
    }

    // テスト結果が表示されない
    public static int Sub(int lhs, int rhs) {
        return lhs - rhs;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class Tests {

    [TestMethod]
    void Test01(){
        Assert.AreEqual(3, App.Add(1,2));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    void Test02(){
        var domain = new TestDomain {
            Lhs = 1,
            Rhs = 2,
            Result = 3
        };
        domain.Run();
    }

}

class TestDomain {
    public int Lhs { get; set; }
    public int Rhs { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }

    public void Run(){
        Assert.AreEqual(Result, App.Sub(Lhs, Rhs));
    }
}
```